# Gradle copy contents of zip dependency into a dedicated folder

Tags: gradle

I have a jar task that is configured to copy contents of my custom defined zip archive dependencies into a particular sub-folder of the jar archive:

```
configurations {
    docs
    javadocs
}

dependencies {
    ...
    docs "mygroup:myartifact:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:docs@zip"
    javadocs "mygroup:myartifact:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:javadoc"
}

jar {
    ...
    from ( configurations.docs.collect { zipTree(it) } ) {
        into 'static/docs'
    }

    from ( configurations.javadocs.collect { zipTree(it) } ) {
        into "static/docs/${name}/${version}/javadoc"
    }

}
```

That works for docs dependencies well. For javadoc, as you can see I need access to the corresponding dependency name and version to copy the content into a specific subfolder of the jar. It would overlap otherwise and I don't control the internal folder structure of the javadocs dependencies.

Is there a way to access/use the Gradle API to achieve the sketched functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (not fully tested; using Gradle 3.5):

```
jar {
    ...
    from ( configurations.docs.collect { zipTree(it) } ) {
        into 'static/docs'
    }

    configurations.javadocs.resolvedConfiguration
        .firstLevelModuleDependencies.each { ResolvedDependency dep ->
            into("static/docs/${dep.moduleName}/${dep.moduleVersion}/javadoc") {
                from(dep.moduleArtifacts.collect { zipTree(it.file) })
            }
        }

}
```

I hacked it together after poking around the Gradle javadoc for `Configuration` [here](https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/javadoc/index.html?org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html).